# Как закрепить bootstrap dropdown элемент, что бы он не закрывался?

Tags: bootstrap

Как закрепить bootstrap dropdown элемент, что бы он не закрывался по нажатию на любую часть выпавшей области, а закрывался по нажатию кнопки внутри этого dropdown или нажатию вне области этого dropdown?

Пример: [здесь](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oWryoo)

По клику на `ELEMENT` не должно пропадать, а по клику на `click` - должно

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('.container').on({
    "shown.bs.dropdown": function() { this.closable = false; },
    "click":             function() { this.closable = true; },
    "hide.bs.dropdown":  function() { return this.closable; }
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
   
<div class="container">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="menu1" data-toggle="dropdown">BUTTON
    <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="menu1">
      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">ELEMENT</a></li>
      <button>click</button>
     
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```